# Приведение к верхнему регистру ключей словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

есть некий словарь `{'-f':'200','-p':'good'}`
надо привести ключи к верхнему регистру, и при возможности перезаписать его в ту же переменную

```
a={'-a':'12','-v':'132'}
print(a.keys())
for i in a.keys():
    print(i)
```

Comment: С чем возникли трудности?

Comment: с обновлением ключей

Comment: Приведите ваш код.

Comment: В вашем коде только перебор ключей словаря. Нет операции приведения строки к верхнему регистру, нет создания нового словаря. Если эти отдельные шаги вызывают затруднения, стоит обратиться к документации или учебным материалам по языку, в крайнем случае задать отдельные вопросы. Хотя, задачу за вас уже решили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1 = {'-f':'200','-p':'good'}

d2 = dict([ [k.upper(), v] for k, v in d1.items()])

print(d2)
{'-F': '200', '-P': 'good'}
```

Answer (score 4):

***Код:***

```py
d = {
    '-f': '200',
    '-p': 'good',
}

d = {k.upper(): d[k] for k in d}
print(d)
```

***stdout:***

```py
{'-F': '200', '-P': 'good'}
```

Я решил воспользоваться генератором словарей для этой задачи.

Итерируя словарь, возвращаются его ключи, которые приводятся к верхнему регистру с помощью метода `upper()` и принимают значение из исходного словаря.